# Displaying the content from an XML file using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt, tags

I've been stuck for days now and any help would be appreciated. I really can't seem to figure out how to create an xslt document that displays the content of an XML document to look like this photo:

[image: how I want to display my XML]

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="digitalLibrarySystem.css"?>
<digitalLibrarySystem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~eom25/657/diglibschema/digitalLibrarySystem.xsd"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">



<systemMetadata>
    <title>Koha</title>
    <creator>by Katipo Communications</creator>
    <subject>library community, research, information services,public 
        libraries, bibliographic management, distributed library systems, metadata, 
    resource discovery, conferences,lectures, workshops</subject>
    <description>Koha was one of the the first open-source Integrated Library Systems 
    It is used and maintained by the worldwide library community.</description>
    <date>2000</date>
    <type>ILS</type>
    <rights>Open-source</rights>
    <identifier>http://www.koha.org/</identifier>
</systemMetadata>
<aboutRecord>
    <recordCreator>Created by Matthew Weidemann</recordCreator>
    <creationDate>on 2018-05-03</creationDate>    
</aboutRecord>
```

I was trying to create a table, but it just doesn't seem to be working. I asked my professor if we were supposed to use a table to display this XML, but days go by without any response and I just feel so unsure of what I am doing.

Thanks

Comment: You can use the HTML elements `<h1>`...`<h6>` and `<i>` and `<b>` for the content. Then you can surround the content with a `<table border="1">`. There you go.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are trying to do this by generating HTML and then viewing the HTML in a browser. (There are other ways, for example generating XSL-FO, converting that to PDF, and then printing the PDF.)

The first thing you need to do is to work out what HTML you want to generate. It's not clear from your post whether your problem is in designing the HTML, or in generating it using XSLT. I get the impression your problem is in designing the HTML (because there is absolutely no reason to use tables for this).

Forget about writing any XSLT code until you know what HTML you want it to produce. Hand-author the HTML until you are happy with it, then think about how to create it from the XML.

Comment: Okay, that helps. Thanks. I am just an old-school, stacks librarian who has found himself way over his head in this very basic XML course. I am having trouble trying to figure out where to start I suppose. I appreciate the advice.

Comment: all I have is this so far.